# Redirect after Devise authenticates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a main app and a help with a shared secret key.  If I am not authenticated in the main app the help site redirects to the main app.  The idea I had was that Devise remembers the path you tried to access the site with and then sends you there after authentication.

I tried this in my main app:

```
get '/help', to: redirect('https://help.mydomain.com'), as: :help
```

The issue is that I get a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.  I want my main app Devise to authenticate first then redirect.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Getting close:

```
    # routes.rb

  authenticated :user do
    get '/help', to: redirect('https://help.insertyour.domain'), as: :help
  end

  unauthenticated do
    get '/help', to: 'home#dashboard'
  end
```

This solves the redirect but created another issue. The help site sends you to the main site (`https://app.insertyour.domain/help`) signup page.  You authenticate and then devise sends you back to the help site and it allows access.  The problem is that if you go back to the main app you have to authenticate again.  It's not idea but works for now.  Not sure why a new attempt to access the main site requires authentication again.

Answer (score 0):

Devise sets the token in a cookie and it's apparently not shared with `help.mydomain.com` (it's a safe default). It the help app is under a subdomain, you can [configure session store, to allow subdomains](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-subdomains):

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', domain: '.mydomain.com'
```

Comment: Yes. That’s exactly why I have. My help site redirects if I don’t have the session active. The redirect works fine if I just go to the app root etc. if I try to redirect to to mydomain.com/help Devise seems to redirect back to the help site before the session is set.